# How to load a keystore, which is inside the resource folder (maven)?

Tags: java, maven, resources, keystore, truststore

I have a custom SSL factory, where I load my own truststore.

Now when I put the truststore.jks file into the project root folder, it works with the following line:

```
ks.load(new FileInputStream("/truststore.jks", passphrase);
```

But I want my truststore inside my resource folder, which was built with maven where the path is **src/main/resources**.

Then I do and it doesn't work with the following line:

```
ks.load(this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/truststore.jks"), passphrase);
```

Though the input stream exists. I checked it. It only fails when I do ks.load(...).

The exception that I get is:

```
 java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Why is that?

Regards, 
Dave

Comment: one thing you could try comes to mind.  Specify "/truststore.jks" in your getResourceAsStream so it searches from the root of the classpath.

Comment: I tried that too, with no luck...

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Strange, it works now...

I had

```
Properties systemProps = System.getProperties();
systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/truststore.jks");
systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperties(systemProps);
```

and change the second line to

```
systemProps.put( "javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "src/main/resources/truststore.jks");
```

Anyone knows why? Is this solution ok?

Comment: This will only work in your local development environment. Once you build your artefact, the path `src/main/resources` will be invalid.

Comment: Please update your original question instead of posting a new question as an answer

Comment: This solution has nothing to do with the fact that the truststore is a resource. Your answer (as noted before me) only works during development, so I does not work!